# What is the reason why the monero firmware is delayed until ringCT is implemented?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, ringct, trezor

What is the reason why the monero firmware is delayed until ringCT is implemented?

Does this mean the firmware has to be re-written to work with ringCT?

Also will the trezor Monero firmware will be implementated in the Monero-wallet-cli?
(I have read so far it need a modified version of it?)

Answer (score 3):

Noodledoodle has held off releasing the firmware as it needs to be reworked to make RingCT compatible transactions. It will be fine to use as is, but the trezor firmware won't be usable after September 2017. I'm pretty sure that's why he hasn't released it yet as it's not going to be much use to anyone if it isn't properly finished. The Monero-wallet-cli code has already been released and simply needs to be merged properly. Probably once it's been reviewed and polished to the devs' satisfaction. I think he has released a more up to date version, but I'm not sure where he posted it. It may be on the github page.

The newest Monero firmware binary is [here](https://github.com/NoodleDoodleNoodleDoodleNoodleDoodleNoo/trezor-xmr-bin).