# Can the concept in a hardware wallet like ledger unplugged be ported over to Monero

Tags: hardware-wallet, trezor, ledger

I'm not a expert but it seems to me that since the source code is out there for the ledger unplugged it might not be that hard to port over. I think that it would help with large investors to feel comfortable with monero. I really like it , it's easy to use and feels very safe to me and can fit in your wallet. Any info or feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not a expert but it seems to me that since the source code is out there for the ledger unplugged it might not be that hard to port over.

That might be the case if Monero was a Bitcoin clone. However Monero uses a completely different codebase than Bitcoin. The Ledger firmware that works for Bitcoin is completely different than what would be needed for a Monero implementation.

If there is sufficient demand for another hardware option after the Monero [Trezor firmware](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/how-does-one-convert-the-trezor-seed-to-a-simplewallet-seed-and-vice-versa) is merged by [Satoshi Labs](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5045bo/satoshi_labs_is_willing_to_merge_monero_on_trezor/) then maybe a Monero developer would consider working on Ledger firmware at that time. Monero developer, NoodleDoodle would like to see his Trezor firmware code updated for [RingCT compatibility](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2232/what-is-the-reason-why-the-monero-firmware-is-delayed-until-ringct-is-implemente) before being merged. Therefore, a large amount of developer focus given to Ledger is unlikely to come soon.